# Alternate groovysh.profile script

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to override the location of the `groovysh.profile` / `groovysh.rc` file on the command line? e.g.

```
GROOVYSH_RC=one_time_groovysh_rc groovysh
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In looking at the source to Groovysh.groovy, it calls this method:

```
File getUserStateDirectory() {
    def userHome = new File(System.getProperty('user.home'))
    def dir = new File(userHome, '.groovy')
    return dir.canonicalFile
}
```

Looks like you could set the "user.home" property to change the root, but it still expects a .groovy inside that directory (-Duser.home="/foo").